# Get appcache Status from page without manifest using iframe trick

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, application-cache

I have to cache two essential pages of my web App using Application cache.
It works great with the iframe trick. Cause I want to cache two specific pages and not the page which has to call the manifest.

But Im not able to get info about the application cache status outside of the two cached pages, which are stored in the application cache (a blank HTML for the iframe and two other pages).

Isnt it possible?

```
window.applicationCache.cache
```

Always returns "uncached". While this page is the one which calls the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Well, assuming the iframe is from the same origin as the containing page, you should be able to access the status like this:

```
document.getElementById('frameid').contentWindow.applicationCache.status
```

And of course replace `frameid` with the id of the `<iframe>` element

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but it works... Using localStorage now. The iframe writes the status in the localStorage and the main page pulls the status from there every few seconds.